# How implement sass:math into vue.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2

I am using vue-cli - Vue on v2.6; sass v1.49 - and using simple division calculations, but I follow receiving errors in the console:

> Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is
> deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

I tried some documentations (['webpack-contrib::implementation'](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#implementation); ['dev.to::how to use dart-sass with vue'](https://dev.to/matiaslopezd/how-to-use-dart-sass-with-vue-1m41)), which asks you to configure vue.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        implementation: require("sass"),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But without success:

> Syntax Error: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has
> been initialized using an options object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - options.implementation should be an object:    object { … }    -> The implementation of the sass to be used
>   (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#implementation).

So how do I implement the use of sass: Math in Vue-cli?

Answer (score 1):

After some time trying some solutions, the easiest has been implemented like this:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: '@use "sass:math";',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

As I use a global variable file, the final setup was like this:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `
          @use "sass:math";
          @import "~@/assets/scss/src/_variables.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
};
```